# get liste of array from methode http angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, symfony

i have a dropdown liste of category of job. this list is loaded when i lanche my page

[image]

whene i chose a category the second dropdown liste is loaded this liste contains a liste of jobe title 
[image]

when i choose  a job title i want to display his skills like this
[image]

every things is good but the problem is juste how can i feed my skills drop down liste.
this my code :

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        var job_arr = {};
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api./dev/profiles/categories/").then(function (response) {
                //console.log(response.data.Categories);
                $scope.myData = response.data.Categories;
                // console.log(response.data.Categories);
            });

            $scope.update = function () {
                $http.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api./dev/profiles/categories/" + $scope.selectedCat).then(function (response) {
                    job_arr = response.data.profiles;
                    console.log(job_arr);
                    $scope.listOffer = response.data.profiles;
                    console.log(job_arr);
                });

                //$scope.listOffer = response.data.profiles;
                //get selected job title
                // console.log($scope.selectedJob);
                //console.log('ffffffffff :' + job_arr);
                var result = [];
                var i;
                var result;
                var html = '';
                for (i = 0; i < job_arr.length; ++i) {
                    if (job_arr[i]["JobTitle"] == $scope.selectedJob) {
                        //normalement  job_arr[i]["Skills"]
                        result = job_arr[i]["Skills"];
                        //console.log(result);
                        $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                            //alert(k + ' is ' + v);
                            html += "<option value =" + v + " >" + k + "<option>";
                        });

                        //$('#myskills').append(html);
                    }
                }
            };
            $scope.updatejob = function () {
                 alert('updatejob');
                $http.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api./dev/profiles/categories/" + $scope.selectedCat).then(function (response) {
                    alert('updatejob');
                    job_arr = response.data.profiles;
                    console.log('eeeeeee:' + job_arr);

                });
            }
            $scope.mySwitch = false;
            $scope.switch = function () {
                // $(window).scrollTop(0);
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
                $scope.mySwitch = !$scope.mySwitch;


            };


        });

    </script>
```

html :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-init="mySwitch=false" > 
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div ng-show="mySwitch" style="font-size: 20px; margin: 31px;text-align: center;background-color: #8bc34a">
                <p>Form has been successfully saved</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <fieldset>                    </fieldset>
            {#<legend>ffffffffff</legend>#}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group "> 
                        <label class="control-label">Age</label>
                        <div  isinline="isInline">    
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" ng-model="myVar1" value="18-24" ng-checked="true">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>18-24
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" ng-model="myVar1" value="25-34">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class=""></span>25-34
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" ng-model="myVar1" value="35-54">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>35-54
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required"  ng-model="myVar1" value="55+">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>+55
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group "> 
                        <label class="control-label">Gender </label>
                        <div id="zaid_user_profile_step2_candidate_hasLicenseB" isinline="isInline">         
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" required="required" value="all" ng-model="myVar2" value="all" ng-checked="true">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>all  
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"   required="required" value="men" ng-model="myVar2" value="men">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>men
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" value="women" ng-model="myVar2" value="women">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>women
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group "> 
                        <label class="control-label">Degree  </label>
                        <div id="zaid_user_profile_step2_candidate_hasLicenseB" isinline="isInline">         
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" required="required" ng-model="myVar3" value="all" ng-checked="true" value="A Levels/High-School Diploma/Baccalauréat">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>A Levels/High-School Diploma/Baccalauréat  
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"   required="required" ng-model="myVar3" value="Bachelor/Licence">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>Bachelor/Licence
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" ng-model="myVar3" value="Master/MS/MSc">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>Master/MS/MSc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" ng-model="myVar3" value="MBA/Doctorate">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>MBA/Doctorate
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio"  required="required" ng-model="myVar3" value="Other">
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>Other
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>  
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Job location</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control user-success" id="zaid_user_profile_step2_candidate_postalCode" name="zaid_user_profile_step2[candidate][postalCode]" required="required" placeholder="Job location">
                            <span class="material-input"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {#<select ng-model="selectedSkills" ng-change="updateskills()">
                    <option ng-repeat="s in myData" value="{{'{{s.Skills}}'}}">{{'{{s.Skills}}'}}</option>
                </select>#}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Personal interests</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control user-success" id="zaid_user_profile_step2_candidate_postalCode" name="zaid_user_profile_step2[candidate][postalCode]" required="required" placeholder="Personal interests">
                            <span class="material-input"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Professional background</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control user-success" id="zaid_user_profile_step2_candidate_postalCode" name="zaid_user_profile_step2[candidate][postalCode]" required="required" placeholder="Professional background">
                            <span class="material-input"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Category </label>
                            <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched user-error" ng-model="selectedCat" ng-change="update()">
                                <option ng-repeat="x in myData" value="{{'{{x.CategoryName}}'}}">{{'{{x.CategoryName}}'}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Job title</label>
                            <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched user-error" ng-model="selectedJob" id="myjobetitle" ng-change="updatejob()">
                                <option>Select a job</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="x in listOffer"  value="{{'{{x.JobTitle}}'}}">{{'{{x.JobTitle}}'}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>           


            <div class="row">                
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Skills</label>
                            <select name="yearof" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched user-error" multiple="multiple" id="myskills">
                                <option value="0">WS</option>
                                <option value="1">Java</option> 
                                <option value="2">Jira</option> 
                                <option value="3">Linux</option>
                                <option value="4">Math</option>
                                <option value="5">OS X</option>
                                <option value="6">Tableau</option>
                                <option value="7">Windows</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>     
            </div>

            <div class="row">                
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 champs-marge">
                    <div class="form-control-wrapper form-group ">    
                        <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                            <label class="control-label">Years of experience</label>
                            <select name="yearof" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched user-error">
                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10+">10+</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>     
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 btn-flow-block">
            <div class="craue_formflow_buttons craue_formflow_button_count_2 text-center">
                <button ng-click="switch()" class="btn-green text-bold" type="button" ng-start-saving="">
                    Enregistrer           
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>           

    </div>
```

---

https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api./dev/profiles/categories

```
{
    "Categories": [
         {
            "CategoryName":"Marketing"
        },   {
            "CategoryName":"Developper"
        },   {
            "CategoryName":"Management"
        }       ]
}
```

and 
https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api./dev/profiles/categories/" + $scope.selectedCat

```
{
    "profiles": [{
        "JobTitle": "DataScientist",
        "CategoryName": "Developper",
        "Salary": "100000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "12",
        "Searches": "423",
        "Skills": {
            "Java": "2",
            "Linux": "9",
            "OS X": "3",
            "Tableau": "32",
            "Windows": "4",
            "Math": "19",
            "AWS": "2",
            "Jira": "10"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "PcMag": "2",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }, {
        "JobTitle": "System Administrator",
        "CategoryName": "Developper",
        "Salary": "100000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "12",
        "Searches": "423",
        "Skills": {
            "Linux": "123",
            "RÃ©seau": "143"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "PcMag": "2",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }, {
        "JobTitle": "Architect Cloud",
        "CategoryName": "Developper",
        "Salary": "100000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "2",
        "Searches": "1423",
        "Skills": {
            "Java": "1",
            "Linux": "90",
            "OS X": "10",
            "Windows": "4",
            "RÃ©seau": "123",
            "AWS": "123",
            "Jira": "120"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "Amazon": "2",
            "Google": "4",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }, {
        "JobTitle": "Architect SI",
        "CategoryName": "Developper",
        "Salary": "180000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "8",
        "Searches": "423",
        "Skills": {
            "Java": "2",
            "Linux": "9",
            "OS X": "3",
            "Tableau": "32",
            "Windows": "4",
            "Math": "19",
            "AWS": "2",
            "Jira": "10"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "PcMag": "2",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for cascading Drop Select.

1- you sould get the data with the ids. so that profil can have the id of the category

you can look at a good example of what you want to achieve here:

[country state and city cascade select drop example](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1189/angularjs-cascading-dropdown-select-with-demo)

hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.employees = {
    "profiles": [{
        "JobTitle": "DataScientist",
        "CategoryName": "Developper",
        "Salary": "100000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "12",
        "Searches": "423",
        "Skills": {
            "Java": "2",
            "Linux": "9",
            "OS X": "3",
            "Tableau": "32",
            "Windows": "4",
            "Math": "19",
            "AWS": "2",
            "Jira": "10"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "PcMag": "2",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }, {
        "JobTitle": "System Administrator",
        "CategoryName": "Management",
        "Salary": "100000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "12",
        "Searches": "423",
        "Skills": {
            "Linux": "123",
            "RÃ©seau": "143"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "PcMag": "2",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }, {
        "JobTitle": "Architect Cloud",
        "CategoryName": "Architect",
        "Salary": "100000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "2",
        "Searches": "1423",
        "Skills": {
            "Java": "1",
            "Linux": "90",
            "OS X": "10",
            "Windows": "4",
            "RÃ©seau": "123",
            "AWS": "123",
            "Jira": "120"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "Amazon": "2",
            "Google": "4",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }, {
        "JobTitle": "Architect SI",
        "CategoryName": "Developper",
        "Salary": "180000",
        "Currency": "EUR",
        "Quantity": "8",
        "Searches": "423",
        "Skills": {
            "Java": "2",
            "Linux": "9",
            "OS X": "3",
            "Tableau": "32",
            "Windows": "4",
            "Math": "19",
            "AWS": "2",
            "Jira": "10"
        },
        "Interests": {
            "PcMag": "2",
            "LinuxMag": "3"
        }
    }]
};
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select name="categoryObj" ng-model="categoryObj" ng-options="item.CategoryName for item in employees.profiles"><option value="">Select Category</option></select>   
<br> <br>

<select name="jobTitleObj" ng-model="jobTitleObj" ng-options="item.JobTitle for item in employees.profiles"><option value="">Select job title</option></select>   
<br><br>
<select name="skill" ng-model="skill" ng-options="key as key for (key , value) in jobTitleObj.Skills"><option value="">Select skill</option></select>   
<br> <br>

Category : {{categoryObj.CategoryName}} <br>
job Title  : {{jobTitleObj.JobTitle}} <br>
skill : {{skill}} <br>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!!..

Comment: thank you for your answer . but i want to get data from url directly its dynamic !

Comment: @AitFrihaZaid you need to write a service for that and you can save it in scope variable..